# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when trying to create a file

Tags: python

I am trying to create a log system which writes to a new file all the exceptions that the program encountered. To achieve this i used the asctime() function in my string creation. However when I trun to run I get the this error:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\VendSend Log Wed Jun 12 17:16:56 2019.txt'

This is the code that I have:

```
reporter_name='C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\VendSend Log '+time.asctime()+'.txt'

fh = open(reporter_name,'w')

fh.write('-----VENDORS WITH NO EMAILS-----')
f_len = len(vendor_removed)
fcount = 0
while fcount < f_len:
    fh.write(vendor_removed[fcount])
    fh.write()
    fcount += 1
```

Comment: You can't have colons in the file name. Use an underscore (`_`) or something

Comment: The colons come from the asctime() function. How would i change that and still keep inputting the time and date into the file name

Comment: Usually, you would use a time function that returns something that can be used in a file name, like [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time). If you want it to be readable, you could use, for example, [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to remove the colon.

Comment: The `time` module is mostly superseded by the `datetime` module. Something like `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')` or `iso` shortcuts

Comment: @roganjosh: Was about to suggest the same thing. Advantage to that over stuff like `asctime` is that that date format will sort ASCIIbetically in order by date string, so sorting by filename gets them in the correct order.

Comment: @jirassimok don't use `replace` when converting a `time`/`datetime` object to a string. That's wasteful. Both modules give you full control of their format when converting to string with `strftime`

Answer (score 0):

time.asctime returns this format 'Sun Jun 20 23:21:05 1993'. As you're on windows and it doesn't accept /:*?"<> or |,  you are specifying a filename which is not legal.

Try time.strftime, it will let you format the date/time any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp in the filename contains invalid characters. Use the following to create a time stamp that can be appended to the filename:

```
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

The output from this can be used to create filenames.

Comment: For this between the year month and date could i put "/" between them? @Roshan

Comment: @rmcknst2 why don't you just try rename a new file in that format and find out? You don't need Python for that --> right click, new file, give it a name with `/` in it. See what happens

Comment: "/" is a reserved character in windows and you might need to escape it. You could just try it out as @roganjosh suggested or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

The output contains invalid characters for a filepath on windows.

Try the [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) method to get a format that only contains acceptable path characters.

```
import time

basename = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\VendSend Log "
logname = "%s %s.txt" % (basename, time.strftime("%a %b %d %H %M %S %Y", time.localtime()))
```

I would also encourage you not to use spaces in the path (**this includes the filename**).